# Error con fechas en Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy desarrollando un script para enviar por correo alertas de vencimiento. Pero se deben enviar 30 días antes de la fecha correspondiente. El problema es que me dice que todos están vencidos, pero hay algunos que no lo están. Se supone que se debe enviar cuando esta a punto de vencer, pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Tengo una tabla en Google Sheets que se llama `PruebaEmail`

Tabla

```html
   A    | B          | C | D
1 Dias  |Fecha       |   | caja@mail.xom
2 30    |18/09/2022  |   |
3 30    |03/09/2022  |   |
4 30    |14/10/2022  |   |
5 30    |08/10/2022  |   |
6 30    |25/11/2022  |   |
7 30    |02/11/2022  |   |
```

Código

```js
function SendEmail(){

  // Obtener dirección de correo
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PruebaEmail").getRange("D2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

  // Fecha
  var fechaLimiteRango = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PruebaEmail").getRange("B4:B10");
  var fechaLimite = fechaLimiteRango.getValue();
  var diasPrevios = 30;

  if(fechaLimite <= diasPrevios){
     Logger.log("faltan x dias");
  } else{
     Logger.log("Vencido");
  }

 // // Enviar alerta
 // var message = 'Prueba!'; // Second column
 // var subject = 'Alerta desde Google Sheets';
 // MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

Comment: Revisa la comparación que estás haciendo. Se supone que estás tomando un rango de fechas y lo estás comparando con `30`? Y debería validar si el rango es menor o igual a 30? Por pura curiosidad, has revisado que hay en `fechaLimite` cuando le asignas el getValue? Eso no va a dar nada por ninguna parte.

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, no, voy a revisar lo que me dices.

Comment: Ya tienes dos respuestas. Revísalas ;)

Answer (score 3):

estas analizando un grupo de fechas pero lo analisas como si fuera un unico valor. debes usar un ciclo for para recorrer cada fila y verficar cada fecha por separado. Tambien Estoy creando la variable diasRestantes con la fecha actual para saber cuandos dias faltan.

```
   function SendEmail(){


   var fechaLimiteRango = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   fechaLimiteRango = fechaLimiteRango.getRange("A1:A10").getValues();
   var diasPrevios = 30;
   
   if (fechaLimiteRango != null) {
  
      for (var i = 1; i < fechaLimiteRango.length; i++) {
         var fecha = fechaLimiteRango[i];
         var fechaLimite = new Date(fecha);
         var hoy = new Date();
         var diasRestantes = Math.round((fechaLimite - hoy) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
         if (diasRestantes <= diasPrevios) {
            Logger.log("Falta menos de " + diasPrevios + " dias para la fecha limite");
         }else{
            Logger.log("Falta mas de " + diasPrevios + " dias para la fecha limite");
         }
      }
   }else{
      Logger.log("No hay fechas establecidas");
   }

}
```

Prueba este codigo, pero debes cambiar las columnas en la variable fechaLimiteRango

Answer (score 2):

No hay forma de que comparar un número (30) con el rango dé algo como lo que esperas. Recorre el rango y valida el getTime de cada uno, comparándolo con otro Date (qué se supone que hace alguien cuando compara una fecha con el número 30???).

Lo otro, tienes que tomar cada valor de fecha, crear un objeto Date con cada uno y obtener el getTime. Si comparas los Date directamente, vas a comparar los objetos y va a comparar las instancias, no el valor.

Ahí ya tienes forma de saber si se pasó o no del límite que dices. Si vas a usar la columna A (el 30 de cada fila), reemplazas el `30` al definir `diasPrevios` por el contenido de la fila correspondiente.

Por último, mira bien cómo se recorre un rango. De hecho, si tienes un rango con varias filas y columnas, puedes hacer un forEach anidado y recorrer las filas y las columnas...

Revisa siempre [la documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates) para hacerte la vida más fácil.

PD. Yo repliqué tu código en una hoja diferente, por eso se llama diferente y los rangos varían un poquitito, pero usé los datos de prueba que indicaste :D

```
const MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;


function SendEmail(){

  // Obtener dirección de correo
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C1");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

  // Fecha
  var fechaLimiteRango = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2:B7");
  var fechaLimite = fechaLimiteRango.getValues();
  var diasPrevios = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 30 * MILLIS_PER_DAY);

  Logger.log(diasPrevios);

  fechaLimite.forEach(function(row) {
      Logger.log(row);
     Logger.log(new Date(row).getTime() <= diasPrevios.getTime());
   
 });

 // // Enviar alerta
 // var message = 'Prueba!'; // Second column
 // var subject = 'Alerta desde Google Sheets';
 // MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```